# Exception when I try use get mapping in Spring Boot and MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have a simple getmapping:

```
@GetMapping(value = "{user}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "userEdit";
    }
```

On my view I provide only entity Id:

```
<tr>
   <td>${user.name}</td>
   <td><a href="/user/${user.id}">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

And finaly in my DB I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

}
```

But when I try to use my controller i get this exception:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). Failed
>   to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'com.newtwitter.model.User'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
>   com.newtwitter.model.User] for value '1'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided
>   id of the wrong type for class com.newtwitter.model.User. Expected:
>   class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.newtwitter.model.User. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got
>   class java.lang.Integer

Can I fix it?

Comment: you can't read user value as "User" type in path variable. try to change the type to String or long

Comment: you can put the user id on the path variable, not the whole User object.

Comment: You can specify a User instance if the Spring Data web extensions are enabled as detailed in my answer.

Comment: you can use Converter to convert user id to User object or else get id from the path variable and then get user from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially your controller method takes a User Object as a param but the framework has a String and this cannot be converted to an instance of a User.

Your code as it stands **is** supported however you need to be using Spring data (which you probably are) and have the Spring Data MVC extensions enabled in order for this conversion to happen automatically.

This is documented in the manual (4.8.2. Web support):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web

which notes that adding `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` to your configuration:

> registers a few basic components:
>
> [including]
>
> **A DomainClassConverter to let Spring MVC resolve instances of
>   repository-managed domain classes from request parameters or path
>   variables.**

**Without the Spring Data web extension** you would need to change the method signature to the following and look up the instance manually.

```
@GetMapping(value = "{user}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable Long userId, Model model) {
        User user = //user userId to fetch
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "userEdit";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting User object in controller but sending an id from front end so this error is occurring so you can Change method to like below.

```
@GetMapping(value = "{id}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        User user = userService.read(id); //read user from the DB by id
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "userEdit";
 }
```

UPDATE :

Otherwise you should follow the below approach to update the user by using modelattribute which will contain the full updated object, you just have to save it to DB directly.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
    public String update(User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel,
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
    {
        //update user
        uiModel.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "updatedSuccess.jsp";
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it, but it's a simple way. I know that Spring can do it for me. And I want to know where i miss.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping(value = "{user}")
```

Change value to string, you can not pass object to endpoint.

```
public String edit(@PathVariable User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "userEdit";
    }
```

Change @PathVariable to @RequestBody, so you can access user as object.Or you can change as below:

```
@GetMapping(value = "user/{id}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
// you can get user information base on id here
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "userEdit";
    }
```